# WordPress Twenty Eleven theme and Responsive support

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I have a simple question about the Twenty Eleven WordPress theme.  I know enough of the WordPress API to develop a theme from scratch, but from searching the internet, it seems a lot of developers use Twenty Eleven for a base, so I decided to go with it mainly because it has Responsive support and it seems like a pretty solid theme.  My only issue with it is that the maximum widths don't seem to work when re-sizing desktop browser window.  I get that it's designed to be cross browser/device compliant, but there's got to be a way to define a max width explicitly with a fluid layout.  I thought about just removing Responsive support and converting to a grid system, but I'd be better off developing one from scratch if I go that route.

Has anyone any ideas as to defining a max width while keeping the Responsive Design and if so, could you please explain because the only way I can see preventing element from overflowing when re-sizing is to remove Responsive completely and convert percentages to pixels.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried by css `max-width: X%;` or put the `width` in % and set a `min-width`?

Comment: Will setting a min-width effect the media types at all?  I'm concerned that revamping the CSS will create design flaws on mobile devices.

Comment: You may choose a very little min-width that all the devices can see (I usually use 300px as min-width in my responsives designs).

Comment: you can see it in: http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/responsive-css-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 650px)
{

/* @media (max-width: 650px) Reduce font-sizes for better readability on smaller devices */


}
```